# cin throwing error message

Tags: c++, macos, g++, cin

I was having issues with another program. It was something like this:

```
if(n < 15000)
{
    printf("I am < 15000");
return 0;
}
else if(n > 19000)
{
    printf("I am > 19000");
    return 0;
}
else if(n > 51000)
{
    printf("I am > 51000");
    return 0;
}
```

If n was above 51000 then it would still return "I am > 19000". I figured I needed to "close the gap" by using `else if(n > 19000 && n < 51000)` so to test this I wrote this program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    printf("Please enter a #: ");
    int block;
    cin >> n;
    if(n <= 10 )
    {
        printf("I am <= 10");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n <= 15000)
    {
        printf("I am <= 15000");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n > 15000 && n <= 19000)
    {
        printf("I am > 15000 and <= 19000");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n > 19000)
    {
        printf("I am > 19000");
        return 0;
    }
    else if(n > 51000)
    {
        printf("I am > 51000");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Trying to compile this gave me this error: "error: ‘cin’ was not declared in this scope"
I am using `g++ <filename>` to compile on mac osx 10.7

Comment: See my post becuae i pointed out also a logical error in your prpgram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use C++ standard input/output streams or use C standard input/outpur streams. It is a bad idea to mix them.

All standard declarations with very rare exceptions are placed in the standard name space `std`

So instead of

```
cin >> n;
```

you should write

```
std::cin >> n;
```

Or place the following directive before using cin

```
using std::cin;
//,,,
cin >> n;
```

Also you should include header `<cstdio>` where function `printf` is declared.

Take into account that **this condition**

```
else if(n > 19000)
```

**is invalid** because it includes all numbers greater than 10000 including numbers greater than 51000

I would write the program the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a #: ";
    int block;
    std::cin >> n;

    if ( n <= 10 )
    {
        std::cout << "I am <= 10";
    }
    else if ( n <= 15000 )
    {
        std::cout << "I am <= 15000";
    }
    else if ( n <= 19000)
    {
        std::cout << "I am > 15000 and <= 19000";
    }
    else if ( n > 19000 && n <= 51000 )
    {
        std::cout << "I am > 19000";
    }
    else if ( n > 51000 )
    {
        std::cout << "I am > 51000";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl; 
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful I was not aware that I was mixing C and C++, also you shed some light on my initial problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

by

```
#include <iostream>
```

you are including symbols in namespace `std`, so to access standard input stream you have to write:

```
std::cin
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `std::cin >> n` would help? Seems like an issue of a namespace to me.